# Call to undefined function odbc_connect via command line (cmd) PHP5

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I'm **using PHP 5, Windows (IIS),** and when i try access the file from command line, i get the following error (via browser, everything works great):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()
```

**My current code is:**

```
$connection = odbc_connect(DATABASE, 'user', 'user', SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER ) or die (odbc_errormsg(). "Error");
```

Also have this extension:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll
```

I read to uncomment (php.ini) line with code `php_odbc.dll`, but i don't have these line and file.

Any tips to help?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to install the SQLServer client software, that extension comes with that install

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have the 
extension=php_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_nts_vc6.dll

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux

Comment: I'm usign Windows with IIS

Comment: Oh, now there I fall short of knowledge

Comment: No problem, you tried. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the IIS and xampp installed and the problem is the environment variables.

I changed the path `C:\xampp\php` to `C:\php` and now, works like expected.